# How do I take the derivative of this integral?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Let $$r(x,y)=\begin{cases} y &\mbox{  if } 0\leq y\leq x \\ x &\mbox{ if } x\leq y\leq 1\end{cases}$$

Show that $v(x)=\int_0^1r(x,y)f(y) \ dy$ satisfies $-v''(x)=f(x)$, where $0\leq x \leq 1$ and $f$ is continuous.

How can I take the second derivative of this? When I try to do it I feel like differentiating under the integral sign will yield $v''(r)=0$ due to $r_{xx}(x,y)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that  $$v(x)=\int_{0}^ x yf(y) dy+\int_{x}^1 xf(y) dy\\\implies v'(x)=xf(x)+\int_{x}^1 f(y) dy-xf(x)\\\implies v''(x)=-f(x)$$ The differentiation results follow from [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).

Comment: is it $\int_x^1xf(y)$ instead of $\int_x^1 xf(x) $ in the first line?

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I am editing it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $r=\min$, hence Lipschitz with rank one, and ${\partial r(x,y) \over \partial x} $ is defined for all $x\neq y$. We see that ${\partial r(x,y) \over \partial x} = \begin{cases} 0, & y<x \\
1, & x<y\end{cases}$. Hence ${r(x+h,y)-r(x,y) \over h} \to 1_{[x,1]}(y)$, which is
integrable (and uniformly bounded by one), hence $v'(x) = \int_x^1 f(y) dy$ and so differentiating again
we have $v''(x) = -f(x)$.